# What does __contains__ do, what can call __contains__ function

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
class a(object):
    d='ddd'
    def __contains__(self):
        if self.d:return True
b=a()
print b.contains('d')  # error
print contains(b,'d')  # error
```

---

<sub>See also: [Override Python's 'in' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217001) for the corresponding how-to implementation question.</sub>

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Like all special methods (with "magic names" that begin and end in `__`), [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) is **not** meant to be called directly (except in very specific cases, such as up=calls to the superclass): rather, such methods are called as part of the operation of built-ins and operators.  In the case of `__contains__`, the operator in question is `in` -- the "containment check" operator.

With your class `a` as you present it (except for fixing your typo, and using `True` instead of `true`!-), and `b` as its instance, `print 'x' in b` will print `True` -- and so will any other containment check on `b`, since `b` always returns `True` (because `self.d`, a non-empty string, is true).

Answer (score 29):

to get your code to do something (although nothing useful):

```
class a(object):

    d = 'ddd'

    def __contains__(self, m):
        if self.d: 
            return True

b = a()

>>> 'd' in b
True
```

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__).

Comment: You meant: if m in self.d: return True

Answer (score 28):

`__contains__` method defines how instances of class behave when they appear at right side of `in` and `not in` operator.

```
class Person(object):
      def __init__(self,name,age):
          self.name = name
          self.age = age
      def __contains__(self,param1):
          return True if param1 in self.__dict__.keys() else False

>>> p = Person('Robby Krieger',23)
>>> 'name' in p
True
```

Comment: More simply, you could write for `__contains__`: `return  param1 in self.__dict__.keys()`

Comment: `param in dict` is sufficient to check if param is a key in dict. There is no need to call keys() on the dict beforehand

Answer (score 9):

```
if self.d:return true
```

`self.d` is the string `'ddd'`. Non-empty strings are always truthy: when you use `if` on `'ddd'` it will always act as if you'd said `if True:`.

I think what you probably meant is:

```
def __contains__(self, item):
    return item in self.d
```

`in` is the operator that calls the `__contains__` method behind the scenes.

Answer (score 9):

Lets see a very simple example of magic method **__contains__** :

Suppose I have class Player and my **__init__** method takes one string argument **name**. In main I have created an object (**obj1**) of class Player.

Now if I want to know if my **obj1** (in this case attribute name of obj1) contains a  particular string, substring or an alphabet, I have to implement **__contains__** method as shown in the example.

If my class has **__contains__** method I can call built-in operator **in** on my custom objects as shown in the example.

```
   class Player():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

    def __contains__(self, substring):
        if substring in self.name:
            return True
        else:
            return False

obj1=Player("Sam")
print ('am' in obj1)    ----> True
print ('ami' in obj1)   ----> False
```