# Override Python's 'in' operator?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, operators, in-operator

If I am creating my own class in Python, what function should I define so as to allow the use of the `in` operator, e.g.

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...

m = MyClass()

if 54 in m:
    ...
```

---

<sub>See also [What does __contains__ do, what can call __contains__ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964934) for the corresponding question about what `__contains__` does.</sub>

Comment: I was actually searching how to override the `is` and `is not` operators. Like a `query = tinydb.Query().field == value`, to also be able to write `Query().field is not None`. But it seems I'm left with `__eq__` and `__ne__` for the time being, which leads to the unpythonic `Query().field != None`. (sarc)

Answer (score 358, accepted):

[`MyClass.__contains__(self, item)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)

Answer (score 276):

A more complete answer is:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = [1,2,3,4,54]

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.numbers
```

Here you would get `True` when asking if 54 was in `m`:

```
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> 54 in m
True
```

See [documentation on overloading `__contains__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__).

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/

Answer (score 3):

Another way of having desired logic is to implement [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__).

If you don't overload `__contains__` python would use `__iter__` (if it's overloaded) to check whether or not your data structure contains specified value.