# Can metaclasses be made iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, metaclass

Trying to create a metaclass that inherits from a parent class, that inherits from JSONEncoder.  However, I am getting the following error:

`TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`

Code looks like:

```
class ParentClass(JSONEncoder):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        ...

    def default(self, obj):
        try:
            return super().default(obj)
        except TypeError as exc:
            if 'not JSON serializable' in str(exc):
                return str(obj)
        raise

class AnotherClass():
    def __init__(...):
        ...

    def do_something(self, *args. **kwargs):
        attrs = {'field1': "FieldOne", 'field2': "FieldTwo"}
        ChildClass = type('ChildClass', tuple(ParentClass), attrs)
        ...
```

Is there anyway to make this `ChildClass` iterable using this method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Make a dynamically created class (as in the class itself) iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970718/python-make-a-dynamically-created-class-as-in-the-class-itself-iterable)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Where does this "JSONEncoder" class come from?

Comment: @jsbueno It's part of the standard [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) module.

Comment: great! Since Python is a concise language, try to post complete working examples, imports included, when asking questions. Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the declaration of the `tuple()` method with `ParentClass`. The input to `tuple()` must be an iterable - change it to `tuple([ParentClass])` or `(ParentClass,)` and the code will work.