# What are the mechanics of the in operator for lists or hashes of classes in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how to implement a list or a hash of objects in Python. More specifically, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217001/override-in-operator-in-python), which was the closest I could get, I saw that by doing:

```
class MyClass(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.numbers = [1,2,3,4,54]

def __contains__(self, key):
    return key in self.numbers

>>> m = MyClass()
>>> 54 in m
True
```

I could use the operator in directly on the class **to check an attribute inside of it**.

My question is an extension of this one. Suppose I have a list or a hash of MyClass objects, that is:

```
list = [m1,m2,m3]
hash = {m1,m2,m3}
```

I would like to use something like:

```
if 54 in list: 
   #do something
if 54 in hash: 
   #do something
```

What methods are necessary to be defined in MyClass so that the in operator works? I am unsure what in does (if is it a ==  that would require an __eq or something else). If you happen to know how one would make .index() work in such case I would appreciate as well.

**Edit: Sorry the initial question was confusing. I hope I made it clear. I am trying to find an attribute that is part of the class, such as the original example of the other question. But now I am trying to do so inside a list or a hash. In a sense, I would like that by asking if an element is inside a list, it asks if it is inside each element of the list.** I am unsure if by using the operator in on a list or a hash it does that, or it compares using ==.

Thank you.

Comment: It is called a *mapping* in Python terminology. The `dict` type, or dictionary, is the default implementation. When you talk about hashes, then you are talking about the opaque values used when storing keys in a mapping.

Comment: This question is far from clear. If you do a list of objects of your class, you just use the operator "in" in that list - you don have to provide nothing on the class. To use in Python `sets` (that you are calling "hashes") just add a "__hash__" method to your class that returns an integer.

Comment: Note that your `hash` name defines a *`set()`* instead, not a mapping. You only have no key-value pairs.

Comment: Apologizes, I made a typo over the question I am correcting it now. What I want is to convention an identifier which is an attribute of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `in` tests for containment, it'll check for *equality* against your custom type.

In other words, `ob in some_sequence` can be seen as:

```
any((ob is contained_ob or ob == contained_ob) for contained_ob in some_sequence)
```

Two custom classes `ob1` and `ob2` test as equal if:

1. They are identical, `ob1 is ob2` is True. They are the same object.
2. If `ob1` has an `__eq__` method, then `ob1.__eq__(ob2)` is tested.
3. If `ob1` has no such method, but `ob2.__eq__()` *does* exist then `ob2.__eq__(ob1)` is tried.

You can also define the `__ne__()` and / or `__cmp__()` methods to make things a little more complicated, but you generally want to avoid toying with this too much in custom types.

Comment: while the any()-line is not quite correct, the rest is precise. An object x where x.__eq__(x) yields false is still `in` [x]. +1

Comment: Isn't it more like `any(ob is c_ob or ob == c_ob.. etc`)?  I thought identity was tested first.  Actually, come to think of it, I think the documentation is wrong on this point-- it says "For the list and tuple types, ``x in y`` is true if and only if there
exists an index *i* such that ``x == y[i]`` is true", but a quick test suggests that even if I force `__eq__` to raise, identity is still tested before equality, and `np.nan in [np.nan]` is true.

Comment: @Martjin so if I understood your answer correct, for testing if 54 in [m1,m2,m3] where each m is an object of MyClass, what I need to define is __eq__ for MyClass, and not __contains__. Is that correct?

Comment: @OeufcoquePenteano: Correct, yes.

Answer (score 0):

As @MartijnPieters said, you should overload the `__eq__()` method. I'm not sure what you mean by the hash/dictionary example you gave.

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = [1,2,3,4,54]

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.numbers

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other in self.numbers:
            return True
        else:
            return False


m1 = MyClass()
m2 = MyClass()
m3 = MyClass()

test1 = 54 in [m1, m2, m3]
print test1
#True
test2 = 666 in [m1, m2, m3]
print test2
#False
```