# Make objects support "in"

Tags: python

I have type of object called "GenomicLocation". I want to support the operation "in" for that object, so that I can write

```
genomic_location1 in genomic_location2
```

if certain conditions are met.

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: This might have been answered, but "in" was too short a keyword to allow for good google searches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217001/override-in-operator-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define the method

`__contains__`

Example:

```
>>> class Thing(object):
...     def __contains__(self, x):
...         return x == 'potato'
...     
>>> t = Thing()
>>> 'potato' in t
True
>>> 'spam' in t
False
```