# Can a flat sequence have 'in' operator in python?

Tags: python, containers

In flat sequences(eg. str, bytes, bytearray etc) can we have `in` operator unlike container sequence(eg. list, tuple, collections.deque etc)? Is there anywhere else we can use `in` operator other than container sequence?

Comment: `str` uses `in` to search for a substring, e.g. `"abc" in "fooabcbar"` is true.

Comment: Oh yes. thanks, that helped..

Answer (score 2):

The `in` operator will work for any class that implements the `__contains__` method.

```
x in y
```

is implemented as:

```
y.__contains__(x)
```

For example, `str` implements `in` to search for a substring, rather than testing for a single element of the collection matching.

See [Override Python's 'in' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217001/override-pythons-in-operator).

Answer (score 0):

1. Any class can implement `__contains__` in any fashion it desires. For example, a class that subclasses `int` can implement `__contains__` so it checks if a number is a factor of the integer that it represents., eg `2 in special_integer(6)`.
2. I tend to disagree with your assessment that `str`, `bytes` (and obviously `bytearray`) are "flat". After all, they are all iterable.

Comment: Did you accidentally delete the rest of point #1? On point #2, you're technically correct, but that said, the rule for operator overloading is "only do it when it's intuitive and necessary"; factor checks would be neither. Just because you *can*, doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: @ShadowRanger 1. I don't think something got deleted.  2. Well, it is just an example :)

Comment: You rearranged and expanded since I comment (moved 2 to 1 and 1 to 2, and finished the thought in old #1/new #2). All's well now.