# How to support the `in` operation in python with a class

Tags: python

What magic method do I have to modify to support the `in` operator. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class DailyPriceObj:
    def __init__(self, date, product_id=None):
        self.date = date
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.sd_buy = None

l = list()
l.append(DailyPriceObj(date="2014-01-01"))
DailyPriceObj(date="2014-01-01") in l # how to get this to return True?
```

In other words, I want my object to "act like" the `date` property, so I can use that to see if that `obj` is in an interable (`date` should be a unique field here).

Comment: @DanielMesejo no I've updated the question to make this more clear.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot do both, `DailyPriceObj(date="2014-01-01") == DailyPriceObj(date="2014-01-01")` and `"2014-01-01" in l` because `"2014-01-01" in l == True` implies `DailyPriceObj(date="2014-01-01") == "2014-01-01"`. At least in my opinion

Comment: @David542 you can define eq base on date, but you, at least, need to check type of other. In your case  for type(other) ==  datetime . In other words, DailyPriceObj(date="2014-01-01") == datetime("2014-01-01")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override Python's 'in' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217001/override-pythons-in-operator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement `__eq__` (and `__hash__` for the sake of completeness):

```
class DailyPriceObj:
    def __init__(self, date, product_id=None):
        self.date = date
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.sd_buy = None

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.date == other.date

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.date)


l = [DailyPriceObj(date="2014-01-01")]
s = {DailyPriceObj(date="2014-01-01")}

print(DailyPriceObj(date="2014-01-01") in l)
print(DailyPriceObj(date="2014-01-01") in s)
```

**Output**

```
True
True
```

From the documentation on [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> Called by built-in function hash() and for operations on members of
>   hashed collections including set, frozenset, and dict. `__hash__()`
>   should return an integer. The only required property is that objects
>   which compare equal have the same hash value; it is advised to mix
>   together the hash values of the components of the object that also
>   play a part in comparison of objects by packing them into a tuple and
>   hashing the tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification -- is the only reason to use the `hash()` function so that it's cast into an `int`? Otherwise, couldn't you just return `self.date` in the `__hash__`?

Comment: Yes, and also because the hash of your object is based on the hash of self.date

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `__eq__` in such a way that both two ways of checking will work:

```
class DailyPriceObj:
    def __init__(self, date, product_id=None):
        self.date = date
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.sd_buy = None

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.date == other

l = list()
l.append(DailyPriceObj(date="2014-01-01"))
# both ways work:
print(DailyPriceObj(date="2014-01-01") in l)  # True
print("2014-01-01" in l)  # True
```