# Python: using __getitem__ in a class and using in to find that item

Tags: python

I do the following

```
class dumb(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.g = {}
    def __getitem__(self,key): return self.g[key] if key in self.g else None
    def __setitem__(self,key,val):
        self.g[key] = val


te = dumb()

te[1]=2

te[1]
Out[4]: 2

1 in te
```

and it hangs..

So if I want to search something like this, how do i do that? Please don't tell me to subclass class dictionary.

Thanks in advance!

Possible relevant question asked here:
[What does __contains__ do, what can call __contains__ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964934/what-is-contains-do-which-one-can-call-contains-function)

Comment: Incidentally, the reason it is hanging is that when there is no `__contains__` method available but there is a `__getitem__`, it tries all possible indices starting at 0. Since your `__getitem__` method never raises an exception (it just returns None) it keeps trying infinitely. (You can put `print key` in the `__getitem__` method to confirm this)

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to subclass dict?

Comment: @mbatchkarov because it uses other functions not specific to dictionary and I dont want to limit it to class Something(Type1,Type2) and all that mro suit follows which is anyway not the case here. ive many methods defined over there.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Insightful! thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `in` to work correctly, you need to override [`__contains__()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/contains-method.html):

```
class dumb(object):
    ...
    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.g
```

By the way,

```
self.g[key] if key in self.g else None
```

can be more succinctly written as

```
self.g.get(key)
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to be able to do something like:

```
    1 in te
```

you have to define `__contains__` method

```
    class dumb(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.g = {}
        def __getitem__(self,key): return self.g[key] if key in self.g else None

        def __setitem__(self,key,val):
            self.g[key] = val

        def __contains__(self, item):
            return item in self.g
```