# Python: Find count of the elements of one list in another list

Tags: python

Let's say I have two lists `list1` and `list2` as:

```
list1 = [ 3, 4, 7 ]
list2 = [ 5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 9 ]
```

I want to find the count of the elements of `list1` which are present in `list2`.

**Expected output is 4** because 3 and 4 from `list1` are appearing twice in `list2`. Hence, total count is as 4.

Answer (score 29):

Use list comprehension and check if element exists

```
c =  len([i for i in list2 if i in list1 ])
```

Better one from @Jon i.e

```
c = sum(el in list1 for el in list2)
```

Output : `4`

Comment: Why build a list here... while the check isn't effficient because of lists, you may as well write this as `sum(el in list1 for el in list2)`

Comment: Hi, what if I want to know the count of each element in a list, as the results would be: [2, 2, 0]

Answer (score 5):

You may use [`sum(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to achieve this with the generator expression as:

```
>>> list1 = [ 3, 4, 7 ]
>>> list2 = [ 5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 9 ]

#         v returns `True`/`False` and Python considers Boolean value as `0`/`1`
>>> sum(x in list1 for x in list2)
4
```

As an alternative, you may also use Python's `__contains__`'s magic function to check whether element exists in the list and use [`filter(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to filter out the elements in the list not satisfying the *"in"* condition. For example:

```
>>> len(list(filter(list1.__contains__, list2)))
4

# Here "filter(list(list1.__contains__, list2))" will return the 
# list as: [3, 3, 4, 4]
```

For more details about `__contains__`, read: [What does `__contains__` do, what can call `__contains__` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964934/what-does-contains-do-what-can-call-contains-function).

Comment: Nevermind that using dunder methods isn't great practice - this will only work on Python 2

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate `first` list and `add` **occurences** of a given number to a `sum` using `count` method.

```
for number in list1: 
   s += list2.count(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use collections.Counter here, so a naive and rather ugly implementation first (mine).

```
list1 = [ 3, 4, 7 ]
list2 = [ 5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 9 ]
from collections import Counter
total = 0 
c = Counter(list2)
for i in list1: 
  if c[i]: 
    total += c[i]
```

This doesn't take into account what happens if you've got duplicates in the first list (HT Jon), and a much more elegant version of this would be:

```
counter = Counter(list2)
occurrences = sum(counter[v] for v in set(list1))
```