# Calculate number of items in one list are in another

Tags: python

Let's say I have two very large lists (e.g. 10 million rows) with some values or strings. I would like to figure out how many items from `list1` are in `list2`.

As such this can be done by:

```
true_count = 0
false_count = 0
for i, x in enumerate(list1):
    print(i)
    if x in list2:
        true_count += 1
    else:
        false_count += 1

print(true_count)
print(false_count)
```

This will do the trick, however, if you have 10 million rows, this could take quite some time. Is there some sweet function I don't know about that can do this much faster, or something entirely different?

Comment: Have you tried sets?

Comment: i recommend using pandas instead of iterating thru the list.

Comment: You don't need `false_count`. It is the same as  `len(list2) - true_count`. Maybe that can save some computing cycles.

Comment: There is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862408/python-find-count-of-the-elements-of- but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using Pandas

Here's how you will do it using Pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
list1 = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(10)]
list2 = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(10)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'list1':list1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'list2':list2})

print (df1)
print (df2)

print (all(df2.list2.isin(df1.list1).astype(int)))
```

I am just picking 10 rows and generating 10 random numbers:

List 1:

```
   list1
0      3
1      5
2      4
3      1
4      5
5      2
6      1
7      4
8      2
9      5
```

List 2:

```
   list2
0      2
1      3
2      2
3      4
4      3
5      5
6      5
7      1
8      4
9      1
```

The output of the if statement will be:

```
True
```

The random lists I checked against are:

```
list1 = [random.randint(1,100000) for i in range(10000000)]
list2 = [random.randint(1,100000) for i in range(5000000)]
```

Ran a test with 10 mil. random numbers in list1, 5 mil. random numbers in list2, result on my mac came back in `2.207757880999999 seconds`

## Using Set

Alternate, you can also convert the list into a set and check if one set is a subset of the other.

```
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
print (set2.issubset(set1))
```

Comparing the results of the run, set is also fast. It came back in `1.6564296570000003 seconds`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the lists to sets and compute the length of the intersection between them.

```
len(set(list1) & set(list2))
```

Comment: This is wrong if there are duplicate elements in `list1`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use Numpy array to translate the lists into a `np.array()`

After that, both lists will be considered as `np.array` objects, and because they have only one dimension you can use `np.intersect()` and count the common items with `.size`

```
import numpy as np


lst = [1, 7, 0, 6, 2, 5, 6]

lst2 = [1, 8, 0, 6, 2, 4, 6]

a_list=np.array(lst)
b_list=np.array(lst2)

c = np.intersect1d(a_list, b_list) 

print (c.size)
```