# which searching method is used by element in list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

When I use the function to check if element is present in list in python by using element in List. Which searching method is used in the background.
 ex  2 **in** [2,3,4,5]

for example in the following code:

```
list=[2,3,4]
if 2 **in** list:
     print(True)
else:
     print(False)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \_\_contains\_\_ do, what can call \_\_contains\_\_ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964934/what-does-contains-do-what-can-call-contains-function)

Comment: why does it matter? Have you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details)

Comment: I think knowing the method used in the background doesn't do any harm, and I was curious about it

Comment: Its just a linear search because lists are not normally sorted. If it is sorted you can use `bisect` for binary searching.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse  thanks I had doubt that it used binary search.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's the code for the implemention in cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9211e2fd81fe1db6f73ded70752b144cc9691ab6/Objects/listobject.c#L446):

```
static int
list_contains(PyListObject *a, PyObject *el)
{
    Py_ssize_t i;
    int cmp;

    for (i = 0, cmp = 0 ; cmp == 0 && i < Py_SIZE(a); ++i)
        cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(el, PyList_GET_ITEM(a, i),
                                           Py_EQ);
    return cmp;
}
```

So as you can see, it's literally just walking through the list from front to back until the requisite element is found. The simplest possible algorithm for something like this. This checks out with [the time complexity guide](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), which says that `x in list` has `O(n)` complexity.

---

Dicts and sets use a wholly different algorithm, because they're hash tables, a completely different data structure. Said different algorithm is almost always more efficient. If you're curious, you can also look at the source codes for [sets](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c) and [dicts](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c) respectively (the latter is much more complicated than the former, it looks like).

Answer (score 2):

The `in` keyword can be used in different ways, but in this case, it's used to check if something contains something else. According to [a documentation page about this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details), the `in` keyword calls `__contains__`, i.e.: `x in y` is the same as `y.__contains__(x)`.

If `SomeType.__contains__` is not defined by `SomeType`...

> ...the membership test first tries iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration protocol via `__getitem__()`.

This would most likely be in linear time (`O(n)`). I say "most likely" because it depends on those implementations.

The in-built `list` type can have elements of different types and is not typically sorted, making binary search impossible (or at least illogical) and therefore, as stated by Green Cloak Guy, the CPython implementation performs the check linearly.

To answer the question in one term, it would be: "Linear Search."