# Any practical differences in between "==" vs "in" or "if in" when checking string index?

Tags: python-3.8

Are there any practical differences between examples below and is better use one than others?

```
s = 'this@mail.is'

for i in range(len(email)):
  print('@' in email[i])

#vs

for i in range(len(email)):
    print(email[i] == '@')
#or

if '@' in email:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *practical* difference... for your example here...
In essence, (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775692/use-and-meaning-of-in-in-an-if-statement) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964934/what-does-contains-do-what-can-call-contains-function)), with `in`, python calls the underlying `__contains__` function.

Thus, in your example. It makes no difference.

---

On the other hand, one could create a module and define a differente behavior for the `__contains__` function.
I guess this would be done more for of an academic purpose, but it *could* still be made.

Answer (score 0):

in checks for substrings
 `"a" in "apple" > True`

== checks if it is exactly the same

```
b=10;
if(b==10)
```