# How to replace a txt file content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, writefile

I have a banned_word list `banned=["things", "show","nature","strange image"]`, ,and I need to read a forum message txt file and replace all the banned words in the forum file by same length asterisks.

This is the forum file

```
Forum ONE 

Are things real?
What is nature?
Show me your image.
You have shown me a strange image, and they are strange prisoners.
```

The expected output is

```
Forum ONE 

Are ****** real?
What is ******?
**** me your image.
You have shown me a *************, and they are strange prisoners.
```

My actual output is

```
Forum ONE 

Are ****** real?
What is ******?
Show me your image.
You have ****n me a *************, and they are strange prisoners.
```

The banned word is case insensitive, so Show with capital S is counted as banned, but shown should not be counted as the banned word.

Below is my code

```
#banned_list
banned=["things","nature","strange image","show"]

#read message
with open("forum1","r")as f:
 message=f.readlines()

#append modified message in a new list
new_forum=[]
i=0
while i<len(message):
  j=0
  while j<len(banned):
    if message[i].__contains__(banned[j]):
        message[i]=message[i].replace(banned[j],len(banned[j])*"*")
        j+=1
    else:
        j+=1
  new_forum.append(message[i])
  i+=1

#write to a new_list
with open("new_forum1","w")as n:
i=0
while i<len(new_forum):
 n.write(new_forum[i])
 i+=1
```

Since this is a school homework, I am not allowed to use for and in. How should I modify my code?

Comment: you have a typo in your banned words: `straneg image`

Comment: Special methods like __contains__ are not meant to be called directly.  See [What does __contains__ do, what can call __contains__ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964934/what-does-contains-do-what-can-call-contains-function)

Comment: i would use `regex` for this type of problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you been told that you're not to use `re`?

```
import re
banned_to_check = banned[:]
while banned_to_check:
    word = banned_to_check.pop()
    regex = r'(?i)\b' + word + r'\b'
    message = re.sub(regex, '*' * len(word), message)
```

It's a bit messier without regex, but you can search the lowercase version of the string, and then manually check the ends of word matches aren't letters.

```
def censor(string, banned):
    string = '¬' + string + '¬' # to prevent out of bounds checks later
    to_check = banned[:]
    while to_check:
        banned_word = to_check.pop()
        prev_idx = 0
        while (idx := string.lower().find(banned_word, prev_idx)) >= 0:
            pre = string[idx-1]
            post = string[idx + len(banned_word)]
            if not pre.isalpha() and not post.isalpha():
                string = string[:idx] + '*' * len(banned_word) + string[idx + len(banned_word):]
            prev_idx = idx + 1
    return string[1:-1] # remove out of bounds addtional characters
```

Comment: re is not allowed either, but i'll try your method first, thanks!

Comment: you get get around not having `for ..  in ..`  using `while` and `pop`

Comment: Ok, the biggest problem for me now is that I can only use very basic keywords and modules, i haven't found  any useful methods to differentiate "shown" "showing" from "show".

Comment: I updated my answer for a non-regex solution